# Windows 7 loses access to network drives

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, network-shares, windows-server-2003

Ok this is an odd one, but is happening often enough its getting quite annoying.

I recently installed Windows 7 on my work computer (about 2 months ago) and every so often I lose access to network shares on our work network.

Its one server in particular - other shares are still working fine.

I have a number of folders mapped as a drive, and all of the ones on a particular file server have lost access.  If I try to access the machine directly (\fileserver\d$) it doesn't work either with this message:

> Windows cannot access \fileserver\d$.
>   You do not have permission to access
>   \fileserver\d$.  Contact your network
>   administrator to request access

Once I reboot the computer, access is restored like it should be.  The computers are all on a domain and my user has administrator level access to the server in question.

Comment: So it just happened again.  Haven't rebooted since I wrote this question on Oct 14th.  Just lost access.

Comment: Ok, some more info - I connected to a VPN (PPTP) and noticed the mapped drives on the server in question are no longer working after I disconnect from the VPN. Other servers I can log into stil.

Comment: Does your default gateway change when you connect to the VPN?

Answer (score 1):

On the remote computer set the user account so that user session doesnt expire.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that the network drives have fixed IPs.

Any NAS, network printer or other device you want to access via the network should be assigned a fixed IP so it doesn't get 'lost'.

This can be done in most router configurations.

Comment: I can still resolve the IP address, and it returns a ping.